# Rails - Should I define default attribute value in model level or in db level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails, we can simply define default attribute value in model level with one macro statement from gem 'default_value_for' or by ourself. On the other side, we can define it in the database level with migration 'default' option. I am confused about which is the best practice of rails, or which way should we used in different scenarios?

Any reply is appreciate! :D

Comment: See [When (not) to use default_value_for?](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/default_value_for#when-not-to-use-default_value_for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you might want to consider.

When you set the default in the application then

- the default can be changed easily and
- the default can be dynamic and
- there are ways to bypass the default

When you set the default in the database then

- changing the default needs a migration (what might be a problem for huge tables)
- it is harder to implement dynamic defaults and then
- there is no way to bypass the default in the application (more secure)

Another option you might want to consider is to override the attributes getter method. This approach only uses the default value when an empty (or invalid value) is returned from the database, it doesn't change the way of storing new values.

```
def foo
  super || 'a default value'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting defaults in the database is generally preferable as ActiveRecord is built around a convention over configuration approach where the database table drives the model - and not the other way around.

However database defaults are *not very smart* - they will always be applied and always have the same static value* (well unless you change the DB schema). In most cases this does not matter.

However if the default value requires some sort of computation like for example setting the default country of a user by IP based geolocation you would need to set the defaults on the application level (model).

Other examples would be:

- columns that store serialized data (not native JSON columns)
- relations that should default to a certain record.

### Where do you set default values in the application?

#### in the model

The simplest example is using model callbacks:

```
class Thing 
  after_initialize :set_defaults, if: :new_record?

  private
    def set_defaults
      self.foo = 'bar'
    end
end
```

The con of model callbacks is that it can be very difficult to control exactly where in your application flow it is happing. For example if the initialization block is expensive you don't want it happening in all your tests.

#### In the controller

If the default value relies on the context of the request such as this example which uses Geocoder for IP based geolocation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def set_default_location(geo)
    u.city    = geo.city
    u.zipcode = geo.postal_code
    u.country = geo.country_code
  end
end

class UserController
  def new
    @user = User.new do |u|
      u.set_default_location(request.safe_location)
    end
  end
end
```

The con is that this can lead to bloated controllers if not carefully kept in check.

#### In a PORO / Factory.

Some would argue that placing too much of your business logic inside your ORM classes (subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base`) leads to violation of the Single Responsiblity Principle and makes your application overly brittle.

```
module ManagerFactory
  def self.new(attributes = {})
    user = User.new(attributes)
    user.add_role(:manager)
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @max thank you for your answer. Would you be able to elaborate on why: "placing too much of your business logic inside your ORM classes (subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base) leads to violation of the Single Responsiblity Principle"?

Comment: Because they have tons of responsibilities - validations, typecasting, persistence, dirty state tracking, i18n etc. Its just that rails tucks it away so its not noticeable upfront.

Comment: * This is not quite true. Postgres for example lets you use user created functions to set defaults. However there is a difference between what is known in the application vs what is known in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I would say when to use it and when not to use it based on the data you want to set as default.

If what you have in mind is a static value to be set as default, example: `false, 0, user`, if you something dynamic in mind to be set as default value. Life a randomly `generated UUID` or a date which changed with respect to the day of creation then you can use `default_value_for` gem.